# count item array returned from $.grep()

Tags: jquery

I am using the $.grep() function http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.grep

```
$.each($.grep( [0,1,2], function(n,i){
  return n > 1;
}),
  function(){    alert(items matched); // do something   }
);
```

How to alert the no. of items that were matched in the alert box? Also how to avoid checking the count on each loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Break it into two steps:

```
var arr = $.grep( [0,1,2], function(n,i){
  return n > 1;
});

if (arr.length) {
    alert("There are some items left after grep!");
    $.each(arr, function(){
        alert(arr.length); // do something
    });
} else {
    alert("No items left after grep!");
}
```

Comment: Yes that works..however if I change the condition to n > 4 and then try, the alert does not fire..any suggestions?